# Audio Player Resize

Tags: html, audio, safari

I've used the HTML5  tags to create an audio player to play a live stream. This plays the stream perfectly however I'd like to reszie the player. I have tried adding width="XXX" height="XX" to it and it makes no difference.

I really want to use HTML5 for this. Is there any way to fix this?

(Browser Safari)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<audio tabindex="0" controls="" preload="" id="player1">
        <source src="http://terrillthompson.com/music/audio/smallf.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
        <source src="http://terrillthompson.com/music/audio/smallf.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
```

My first try I was getting the resize too, this seems to fix the issue when starting to play it. If the user "seeks" it still wants to resize...aww crackers XD

It seems to resize because of the (controls="") if we could add an event listener for ("onseeking") and some how reset "controls" back to "blank" that may do it...just an idea at this point, im unsure how to test.

Something like this may help/work

```
var audio = this.audio;
    audio.addEventListener('seeking', function() {
      finish(somehowresetcontrolstoblank);
    }, false);
```

Hopefully this gives someone an idea they can run with :)

Sorry I can only answer half the question